# NSUserDefaults valueForKey error

Tags: swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save a highscore in a simple game. I am new to swift 2 and not sure what I am doing wrong. i am getting the error that "Value of type 'int' has no member for 'valueForKey'. Here is my code as of my last unsuccesful attempt.

```
var highScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if(highScoreDefault.valueForKey("highScore") != nil){
        highScore = highScore.valueForKey("highScore") as NSInteger! //error here
    }


  newFunc
        score += 1
        if (score > highScore){
            highScore = score
            var highScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            highScoreDefault.setValue(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
            highScoreDefault.synchronize()
        }
        highscoreLbl.text = "\(highScore)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple to set value in NSUserDefault

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(yourScore, forKey: "highScore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save it like :`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScore")`

and retrieve it like : `var highScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highScore")`

Answer (score 1):

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setValue(value, forKey: "highScore")
```

Apple recommends to only call synchronize() in special circumstances like when the app is about to exit.

> The synchronize() method, which is automatically invoked at periodic
>   intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults
>   database.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
let highScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//Set
highScoreDefault.setInteger(yourInt, forKey: "intKey")
highScoreDefault. synchronize()

//Get
highScoreDefault.integerForKey("intKey")
```